# PayPal CreateAndSendInvoice

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox

I tried CreateAndSendInvoice API on paypal API explorer. It worked fine. Created invoice and send it to customer. But the problem is, it sent invoice on paypal account of customer but not on his personal account. How to send this invoice to personal accounts instead of paypal account ?

Comment: The invoice email is sent to whichever email address is set in the payerEmail field. Is that not the behavior you are seeing?

Comment: no... it is sending email with invoice... but not on the paypal account associated with mail. If Im sending invoice on a@gmail.com then it should send invoice on gmail account and not on paypal account. So is it possible ?

Comment: Are you talking about the send from email that's getting used?  When using the invoicing system it's going to send the invoice from PayPal's server, so the send from will always be their's.

If you want to send from your own email you could make your own invoicing system and setup payment with Express Checkout instead of using the actual PayPal Invoicing API.